# How can i call a specific tab activity from another regular activity in android by using intent

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have 3 tabs (act1,act2,act3) and i have activities without tabs(A,B), if the user open activity A and press button OK then alarm will start and after 10 seconds it will go to act2

this all done, but i tried many thing :

1- when i go to act2 it does not display the tabs. just act2 activity

so i change the code and tried to :
2- when i go to activity tabs it show me the first tab(act1) but i wanna act2

how can i do it
i wanna display act2 with tab

Give me any reference or hint.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Send an intent (via startActivity() as usual) to bring the activity to the front which contains the tabs. Send an extra parameter with the activity containing the TAG or some identifier for tab, you want to be opened. Evaluate the extra parameter in the activity, which contains the tab and let it switch to the tab as indicated by the parameter.

EDIT

To start the tab activity with a parameter:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, YourTabActivity.class);
i.putExtra(TAB_TAG, tag);  // TAB_ID see comment below, define some tags for the tabs
this.startActivity(i);
```

To extract the parameter from the intent:

Overwrite `onNewIntent()` in the tab activity and introduce a field `lastIntent`, set `this.lastIntent = this.getIntent()` there. (Otherwise you will always access the intent which started the activity in the first place, not the most recently sent intent!)

in `onResume` process the last intent:

```
final Bundle extras = this.lastIntent.getExtras();
final String tabTag = extras.getString(TAB_TAG);    // define the key TAB_TAG as static string
```

Now use `tabTag` to set the current tab.

Comment: Thank you, can you please give me the code, i do not get it. Thank you again

Comment: thank you if u execues me, let me tell you what i get from your solution, i put i put this `final Intent i = new Intent(this, myTabActivity.class);
i.putExtra(TAB_TAG, tag);  // TAB_ID see comment below, define some tags for the tabs
this.startActivity(i);` inside onClick in alarm code, also i put this code in alarm code `public void onResume() {
 extras = this.MyPage.getExtras();
 final String tabTag = extras.getString(TAB_TAG); 
 
}
`then i put this inside the tabs activity    `public void onNewIntent(String j){this.mypage = this.getIntent();}` am i right? because it gives me an syntax error

Comment: What does it say? Did you add the @Override annotations and did you define the static String TAB_TAG? (You need to prefix the class name in the activity which does not define it.)

Comment: i have 3 activities, 1- that have the tabs(just the menu of tabs) 2- (has specific tab) like tab code and information 3-the activity without tab (that it will have the intent button), so please explain exactly where should i put your code. Thank you, REALLY THANK YOU

Comment: Activity 3 gets the code sending the intent, activity 1 gets the code receiving the intent.

Comment: in send the intent, should i send him to activity 1 or 2 ? i mean for the specific tab or for the menu ?